# Problem in refreshing FeatureLayer in Openscales

Tags: openscales

I have a refresh feature layer problem, because I need to delete all the markers and add the new markers so I tried this piece of code, but it doesn't work :(

```
            //refresh
            markers.clear()
            markers.reset();
            markers.removeFeatures(markers.features);
            markers.redraw(true);
            //refresh

            trace(markers.features,"features before");
            trace(Snaps ,"Snaps" );
            for each(var Car in Snaps)
                {
                    var mat = Car[0];
                    var Loc = Car[2];
                    var snap_id = Car[1];
                    var direction = Car[3];
                    //Alert.show(Loc[0]);
                    var marker:CustomMarker = CustomMarker.createUrlBasedMarker("images/markers/iconFlag1up_.png", new Location(Number(Loc[1]),Number(Loc[0])));
                    marker.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,handlesClickMarker); 
                    marker.name=snap_id;

                    markers.addFeature(marker);//add marker to markers
                }

                trace(markers.features,"features after add");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem :)

this is the code that i used :)

```
            trace(Snaps ,"Snaps" );
            var i = 0 ;
            trace(map.featureLayers.length ,"layers count " );
            trace(map.featureLayers ,"layers  " );

             if(markers == null){
             markers= new FeatureLayer("markers");
             markers.projection = new ProjProjection("EPSG:4326");

             markers.style = Style.getDefaultPointStyle();
             map.addLayer(markers);
             trace("markers layer just has been created " );
             }else
                 markers.removeFeatures(markers.features);

            for each(var Car in Snaps)
                {
                    var mat = Car[0];
                    var Loc = Car[2];
                    var snap_id = Car[1];
                    var direction = Car[3];
                                            var marker:CustomMarker = CustomMarker.createUrlBasedMarker("images/markers/iconFlag1up_.png", new Location(Number(Loc[1]),Number(Loc[0])));
                    marker.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,handlesClickMarker); /
                    marker.name=snap_id;

                    markers.addFeature(marker);

                }
```